# Flyway Doesn't Close Connection After Calling To connection.close

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, flyway

I'm using flyway in my application.
Whenever the application loads, I'm calling the flyway.migrate() function.
After my application starts up i don't need flyway for any further task therefore I would like to release this resource and close the connection.
the following block describes what I'm trying to do:

```
 fun initFlywayAndMigrate() {
      val flyway = Flyway.configure()
        .dataSource(
          "jdbc:postgresql://host:ip/db-name",
          "user"),
          "password")
        )
        .connectRetries(3)
        .schemas("my-schema")
        .load()

      flyway.migrate()
      val conn = flyway.configuration.dataSource.connection
      try {
        conn.close()
      } catch (t: Throwable) {
        println(t.message)
      } finally {
        println(flyway.configuration.dataSource.connection.isClosed)
      }
    }
```

It seems that connection is never closed since I do get a "false" print everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're closing the connection, not the datasource.

What this boils down to is:

```
// Get a connection
val conn = flyway.configuration.dataSource.connection

// Close it
conn.close()

// Get another connection and see if it's closed
flyway.configuration.dataSource.connection.isClosed
```